# Group by two columns

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

The database table contains goal actions.

```
 type      goal      assist
 goal      Johnny    James
 goal      Johnny    James
 goal      James     Bob
```

When using *GROUP BY goal, assist* it displays

```
 player    goals     assists
 Johnny    2         0
 Johnny    0         0
 James     1         0
 James     0         2
 Bob       0         0
 Bob       0         1
```

but I need it to show players' goals and assists in one line. Cheers.

Comment: Can you show the query that lead to this result?

Comment: Why not wrap what you have in another query that uses `select player, sum(goals),sum(assists) from (<your query>) group by player`?  Still, you need to show your original query... `group by player` should be all you need for the original

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it like this (although that might not be the fastest query, depending on the size of your database and indexes!):

```
SELECT players.player,
      -- Use correlated subselects to count goals / assists
      (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM actions WHERE goal = players.player) goals
      (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM actions WHERE assist = players.player) assists

-- Get all distinct players (UNION = DISTINCT, here). Of course, if you
-- have an actual players table, use that one instead!
FROM (
  SELECT goal player FROM actions UNION
  SELECT assist      FROM actions
) players
```

From your question, I'm not sure if `type = goal` is relevant for your query...

Answer (score 1):

A possible solution would be to unpivot the player names first, then group with pivoting:

```
SELECT
  Player,
  COUNT(NULLIF(ScoreType, 'assist')) AS goals,
  COUNT(NULLIF(ScoreType, 'goal')) AS assists
FROM (
  SELECT
    CASE s.ScoreType WHEN 'goal' THEN goal ELSE assist END AS Player,
    s.ScoreType
  FROM GoalActions
  CROSS JOIN (
    SELECT 'goal' AS ScoreType
    UNION ALL SELECT 'assist'
  ) st
) s
GROUP BY
  Player
```

Unpivoting is done using a cross join to a virtual table, and grouping/pivoting is implemented in the form of aggregating with CASE.